# how to add keyword search feature for each visualization in kibana4

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I want to add Keyword Search Feature for every Visualization in Kibana.

but i want the feature like(for each visualization):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aeqaehgkry3w9fm/image.jpg?dl=0

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you want isn't exactly possible in Kibana in native form. You can add filters by interacting with the dashboard but no dynamic drop-downs.

I assume you want the filters on one visualisation to update other visualisations appropriately? If so, I think your only option to get the functionality you crave is to roll your own using something like angular.

Comment: thank you for your reply greggers, if possible please suggest some basic guides.